# Parse multi level JSON with Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, hashtable

I am trying to parse the JSON file below. The problem is I cannot return "Mountpoint" as a key.  It only gets parsed as a value.  This is the command I am using to parse it `json_data = JSON.parse(readjson)`.  The reason I guess that it's a key is because if I run json_data.keys only EncryptionStatus and SwitchName are returned.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```json
{
  "EncryptionStatus": [
    {
      "MountPoint": "C:",
      "VolumeStatus": "FullyEncrypted"
    },
    {
      "MountPoint": "F:",
      "VolumeStatus": "FullyEncrypted"
    },
    {
      "MountPoint": "G:",
      "VolumeStatus": "FullyEncrypted"
    },
    {
      "MountPoint": "H:",
      "VolumeStatus": "FullyEncrypted"
    }
  ],
  "SwitchName": [
    "LAN",
    "WAN"
  ]
}
```

I tried using dig as a part of my `JSON.parse` but that didn't seem to help me.

Comment: "MountPoint" is a key contained in each Array element under the "EncryptionStatus" key. I am unclear on what your desire is but `json_data["EncryptionStatus"].map {|h| h["MountPoint"]}` will return an `Array` of the values for the MountPoint keys.

Comment: What is the output that you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON data can have multiple levels.

Your JSON document is a

Hash (Dictionary/Map/Object in other languages) that has two keys ("EncryptionStatus", "SwitchName"),

The value for the "EncryptionStatsu" key is an Array of Hashes (with keys "MountPoint" and "VolumeStatus").

```
# assuming your JSON is in a file called "input.json"
data = File.read("input.json")
json = JSON.parse(data)
json["EncryptionStatus"].each do |encryption_status|
  puts "#{encryption_status["MountPoint"]} is #{encryption_status["VolumeStatus"]}"
end
```

This will print out

```
C: is FullyEncrypted
F: is FullyEncrypted
G: is FullyEncrypted
H: is FullyEncrypted
```

If you want to access a specific item you can look at the `dig` method. E.g.

```
json.dig("EncryptionStatus", 3)
```

Would return the information for mountpoint "H"

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments.  This information has been great to help me understand whats happening here.  Thank so all very much for taking the time to respond.